# OpenGl in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm trying to start learing opengl and I use VS2010 ultimate sp1 but when I add opengl headers I'm getting errors which indicate that there are errors in files not created by me.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

errors (195 in total) this is I think the most common one:
Error   1   error C2008: '$' : unexpected in macro definition   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h 142

Comment: Have you tried using GLee? ( http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/ )

Comment: What is the **first** error message?

Comment: Obviously the _ PREFAST _ macro is defined. But I don't really know what causes it. As you are using VS2010 ultimate you may have switched on a wrong option that causes this. Google reveals it may have to do with some code analysing tool (called PREfast). As a workaround try recreating your project with default options.

Comment: make an empty project. and include opengl libs and header to the project. There shouldn't be any errors

Comment: Slightly Off Topic: You should not use backslashes in include directives but regular forward slashes. Also you should use the proper case of the include file names, which are `GL/gl.h`, `GL/glu.h` and `windows.h`. Last but not least you should surround your inclusion of `windows.h` with tests for the `_WIN32` macro: `#ifdef _WIN32 #include <windows.h> #endif`

Comment: @datenwolf: I agree completely, but backslashes are allowed between the angle brackets in the filename for a `#include` -- it's implementation-defined which characters are permitted, and the Microsoft compiler permits backslashes.  It's not portable, but it's perfectly allowed in this particular toolchain.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Indeed Backslashes are allowed, however Windows and thus VC++ perfectly well accepts forward slashes at path separator. Also if you want to make your program portable doing it that way makes things a lot easier. I know, stdafx.h is a VC++ thing, so no portability anyway, but still I wanted this being said.

Answer (score 5):

Please check that you didn't disable Microsoft C++ extensions.
$ as a part of identifiers is a part of these extensions, so driverspecs.h won't compile when they are disabled.
Command line switch is /Za, also this option is the top-most in Language section in project properties in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be windows.h stuff conflicting with opengl definitions. You don't really need windows.h for a simple command line application like this one. 
Another possibility is the precompiled headers option (stdafx.h) I usually disable it in the compiler options when I  deal with OpenGL and other cross platform projects as dependencies they bring in usually don't agree well with ported code

Comment: You still need to include `windows.h`; you can't create a window without one. And you can't initialize OpenGL without creating a window.

Comment: That depends on whether he is trying to use GLUT or WGL. GLUT wouldn't require library user to include OS specific headers.

Comment: And this brings up another question: which implementation of OpenGL are you trying to use ?

Comment: @AlexK: Actually on Windows you have to include windows.h before GL/gl.h because the Windows variant of that header makes use of some macros defined therein. So it's become canonical to add a `#ifdef _WIN32 #include <windows.h> #endif` in OpenGL code meant to be portable.

Comment: @AlexK well, that's the headers supplied with VS so I suppose it's theirs?